# How determine two pairs of numbers are equal

Tags: math

I have pairs of 2 numbers. let's say I have (A,B) and (X,Y)
Question is:

```
if 
A-B = X-Y and
A+B = X+Y and
A/B = X/Y and 
A*B = X*Y
```

can I conclude A=X and B=Y ?

Comment: Stack overflow is a for **programming** questions. This is not relevant to programming. Please find your answer somewhere else.

Comment: @Majora320, so why there is a tag for math and descrete-math? doesn't it mean we can ask such questions?

Comment: @FLICKER The math tag exists because some programming problems involve math. As it stands though, your question is purely math with no programming component and so is off-topic. math.stackexchange.com may be more suitable.

Comment: @DPenner1 My question is about to solving a programming problem. I had to add the programming issue, I agree. Thank you for reminding me the context of stackoverflow. Regards...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe so:

```
A-B = X-Y so
A = X-Y+B and
B = -X+Y+A so if
A+B=X+Y then
A-X+Y+A=X+Y becomes
2A=2X or A=X
and if
A+B=X+Y then
X-Y+B+B=X+Y becomes
2B=2Y or B=Y
```

Comment: So are you saying there is no need to multiply and division?

Comment: seems like the first two constraints are all that are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the number type. For `float`, you cannot conclude `A = X` and `B = Y`.

Assume `A = 1; B = Positive Infinity; X = 2; Y = Positive Infinity;`

Then `A-B = X-Y = Negative Infinity;` `A+B = X+Y = Positive Infinity;` `A/B = X/Y = 0;` `A*B = X*Y = Positive Infinity;`